# Rails writing a record to a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie.
I have a table called statuses.  It contains status changes for records in a table called requests.

When a user creates a new request, I'd like to write a record to statuses.

How would I go about that?

Thanks

Comment: Is there an ActiveRecord association between Record and Status (eg :has_one, :belongs_to, :has_many etc)

Comment: Just to clarify you'd like to create a status record when a request record is created and I'm assuming also when the request status field is changed. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use after_save callback:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :add_status_chanage

  def add_status_change
    status = Status.new
    status.record_id = id
    status.field = field
    status.save
  end

end
```

Comment: Kuba, - thanks - would that code go into the requests_controller.rb?